# Call the query from another sheet and change it to the lower and proper

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EYRH0qlSUMXwqc2pUFKnwrsQ_a4nPO9Xs-CjEgBfx9Q/edit#gid=0

I would like to display other dare sheet data with the following conditions:
if the data in column `C` has Mosque, Temple, Church then the data in column `C` is changed to Proper and otherwise, the data in column `C` is changed to Lower.

I have made the formulation but the result is an error,

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fLmq8dxqPgDUEHDsJ42qHsviCvIeQGNGWDQ-Z6GXURY/edit#gid=0

```
=Arrayformula(if(or(importrange(H2,"Sheet1!C2:C")="Mosque",importrange(H2,"Sheet1!C2:C")="Church",importrange(H2,"Sheet1!C2:C")="Temple"),
proper(query(importrange(H2,"Sheet1!C2:C"),"Select C Where A = 'New' And D = 'Done'"),lower(query(importrange(H2,"Sheet1!C2:C"),
"Select C Where A = 'New' And D = 'Done'")))))
```

so I ask for the solution sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to import full range for query `importRange(H2,"Sheet1!A2:D")` not only column C.
I don't know why but with `importrange` it looks like `query` only accepts using `Col1` instead of `A`, `Col2` instead of `B` and so on.. so this way should work

```
=Arrayformula(if(or(importrange(H2,"Sheet1!C2:C")="Mosque",
importrange(H2,"Sheet1!C2:C")="Church",
importrange(H2,"Sheet1!C2:C")="Temple"),
proper(query(importrange(H2,"Sheet1!A2:D"), "Select Col3 Where Col1 = 'New' And Col4 = 'Done'")),
lower(query(importrange(H2,"Sheet1!A2:D"),"Select Col3 Where Col1 = 'New' And Col4 = 'Done'"))))
```

Comment: The resulting formula is not as desired.
Bussines type other than Mosque, Temple, Church still "Proper", should be "Lower".